# My code is only returning two of the five entries I need, how can I fix this problem?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a list of employees showing their first name, hire date, and the city where they work. There are five employees listed but when I run my problem it only returns the first two from the location data entry.

Shown first is my employee data entered. When I run a select * statement for this table everything appears as it should. The problem comes when I try to run the second script shown, where it only shows the first two entries from the employee table.

## first

```
INSERT INTO `salon`.`employee`
(`employee_id`,
`first_name`,
`last_name`,
`title`,
`hire_date`,
`termination_date`,
`email`,
`phone`,
`location_id`,
`manager_id`)

VALUES
(1,
'Jenny',
'Jensen',
'Owner',
'2013-06-15',
NULL,
'jensenj@salon.com',
2081112222,
1,
NULL),

(2,
'Haley',
'Lopez',
'Assistant Manager',
'2013-08-23',
NULL,
'lopezh@salon.com',
2083334444,
1,
1),

(3,
'Robert',
'Green',
'Associate',
'2014-01-03',
NULL,
'greenr@salon.com',
2085556666,
1,
2),

(4,
'Olive',
'Adams',
'Manager',
'2015-07-12',
NULL,
'adamso@salon.com',
2087778888,
2,
1),

(5,
'Julie',
'Davis',
'Associate',
'2015-10-20',
NULL,
'davisj@salon.com',
2089990000,
2,
4);
```

## second script

```
SELECT employee.first_name, hire_date, location.city

FROM employee

JOIN location ON employee.employee_id = location.location_id
```

Comment: **JOIN location ON employee.employee_id = location.location_id** this doesn´t make any sense. Employee id needs to be equal to location id???? Where is your location table?? Maybe it should be **JOIN location ON employee.location_id = location.location_id**

Comment: You were right thank you! I totally missed that